# エスケープ文字とは

Tags: java, ruby, bash

エスケープ文字についてよくわからないのですが、

バックスラッシュなどを表現する場合に「¥¥」のように表現しているのですが、
「エスケープ文字」としてきまった文字があるのでしょうか？

http://home.a00.itscom.net/hatada/c01/escape01.html
ここなどをみると「C言語のエスケープ文字」とあり、
言語によって異なるものなのでしょうか？

Comment: この質問は「言語によって異なる→YES/NO」の回答を求めているのか、挙げられている言語・環境ごとのエスケープ文字を聞いているのか、ハッキリした方が良い質問になると思います。

Comment: 真の問いは、エスケープ文字というのはいったいどういう概念なのか、というようにも見えます。

Answer (score 3):

異なります。

Javaに関しては、ここの「Escape Sequences」のセクションに記載されています。

[The Java™ Tutorials - Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

「"Escape Sequences" ruby」のようなキーワードでググってみれば、他の言語についても分かると思います。

Answer (score 3):

エスケープ文字は`\`とは限らず言語ごとに異なります。

一例として[Windowsのバッチファイル](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Quoting_and_escaping)の場合、

- `<`、`>`、`|`、`&`、`!`などの記号は`^`でエスケープします。`^`自身も`^`でエスケープします。
- 変数を表す`%`は`%%`と重ねることでエスケープされます。

Answer (score 2):

エスケープ文字およびエスケープシーケンスは、各種言語において「文字」あるいは「文字列」の中で、ソースコードの見た目と違う機能を引き出す処理と考えていいでしょう。

んで [c](/questions/tagged/c) も [java](/questions/tagged/java) も [python](/questions/tagged/python) あるいは [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) も、エスケープ文字として逆斜線文字を採用し、エスケープシーケンスも似通っています（同一でないので要注意：各言語の仕様書なり解説書なり参照のこと）何か理由なり根拠なりありそうです。

これは妄想ですが、各種言語は、古くからある [c](/questions/tagged/c) 言語のユーザーを自分の陣営に取り込みやすくするため、移行中の [c](/questions/tagged/c) ユーザーが混乱しないよう [c](/questions/tagged/c) 言語に似せたエスケープ文字（エスケープシーケンス）を採用したと個人的には思います。なので、エスケープ文字として「決まった文字」があるわけではないけれど、わざわざ独自の仕様を採用して皆を混乱させるくらいならほぼ同じものにしてしまおうという暗黙の合意があったのではないか、と考えることはできそうです。

そういう事情に関係ない `cmd.exe` や `PowerShell` のエスケープは文字もシーケンスも異なります。

---

[c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) においてはエスケープシーケンスに似て非なる「トライグラフ」というのがあり、文字（列）リテラルでないところでもソースコード上に「クエスチョンマーク２つ＋特定文字」があると、別の文字に読み替えるという変態な機能が盛り込まれています（いやもちろん採用された根拠はきっちりあるのですが）。

```
??=define arraycheck(a,b) a??(b??) ??!??! b??(a??) // と記述すると
#define arraycheck(a,b) a[b] || b[a] // と読む
```

これを知らないプログラマが [c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) でうっかり `??` を書いてしまうとバグらせてしまうことがありうるので要注意です。
https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-pre07-c.html

これのせいで [c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) のエスケープシーケンスには `\?` が存在します（ほかの言語には無いはず）

[gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) では標準で無効、コンパイルオプション `-trigraphs` で有効化したら使えるようになる機能なうえに `-Wtrigraphs` で警告されるほど嫌われていました。また [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) では廃止になっちゃいました。

Comment: C++言語の場合、トライグラフとは別に[代替トークン](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)が用意されていますね。こちらは廃止されていません。

Comment: 代替トークンは文字置換ではないので罪は薄いですよね。実用されている程度はどっこいどっこいでしょうか。オイラ個人的にはトライグラフも代替トークンも使ったことないし、他人のコードで使ってるのも見たことない感じ。

Comment: トライグラフが廃止された理由のひとつに代替トークンの存在がある（と思う）ので、廃止を説明するのであれば、代替トークンの説明をしないのは片手落ちかなということで、コメントしました。